# Facebook and iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, fbml

Hey people, why won't this code work? The Facebook API is so bad it's annoying...
[edit] I felt that wasn't heavy handed enough, it's not only annoying, it's downright backwards and the documentation is dire at best....[/rant]

```
<a href="#" id="click" onclick="outside_location.setInnerFBML(link_1);">Go go go</a><br />

<div id="outside_location"></div>
<fb:js-string var="link_1">
<fb:iframe height="500" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; border:none" src="http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc/fb/index.php"></fb:iframe>
</fb:js-string>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var outside_location = document.getElementById('outside_location'); 
</script>
```

To elaborate, let's backtrack... The Facebook API states that I can have a `fb:iframe` oon a static FBML page, so... if I only have the following, it should work:

```
<fb:iframe height="500" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; border:none" src="http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc/fb/index.php"></fb:iframe>
```

Alas nothing happens, any idea why?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Where is `temp_test` defined?

Comment: Edited, no need to vote me down for a typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you link to it?

Is it an installable application in a page? If that's the case, you can't embed an iframe without the user interacting with your application first.

I think that's the case, and yes, the Facebook documentation sucks and that's a compliment.

Comment: Afraid I cannot link to it, bound by contract. However, I have a horrible feeling that you are right...